# Set simplification.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to solve a problem for Discrete Math homework. The problem is to simpliyfy (b ∩ c) - (a ⊕ b).
So far I've managed to get it down to (b ∩ c) - (A ∪ B) - (A ∩ B). But, I don't know how to proceed from here. How would I finish this?

Answer (score 0):

Draw a [Venn Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) to understand three sets relationship.